# checking oozie installation and example

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Just now I installed oozie-3.3.2 on centos6.5 and I am using hadoop-1.2.1 my question is after executing this example what is this error
 "0000000-140528164444736-oozie-dsri-W@mr-node                                  ERROR     job_201405281644_0001  FAILED/KILLEDJA018     ".
and please suggest me some more oozie example..

[dsri@master oozie-3.3.2]$ oozie job -oozie http://master:11000/oozie -config /home/dsri/oozie-3.3.2/examples/src/main/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
job: 0000000-140528164444736-oozie-dsri-W

[dsri@master oozie-3.3.2]$ oozie job -oozie http://master:11000/oozie -info 0000000-140528164444736-oozie-dsri-W
Job ID : 0000000-140528164444736-oozie-dsri-W
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workflow Name : map-reduce-wf
App Path      : hdfs://master:9000/user/dsri/examples/src/main/apps/map-reduce
Status        : KILLED
Run           : 0
User          : dsri
Group         : -
Created       : 2014-05-28 11:20 GMT
Started       : 2014-05-28 11:20 GMT
Last Modified : 2014-05-28 11:20 GMT
Ended         : 2014-05-28 11:20 GMT
CoordAction ID: -

Actions
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                                                                            Status    Ext ID                 Ext Status Err Code  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000-140528164444736-oozie-dsri-W@:start:                                  OK        -                      OK         -         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000-140528164444736-oozie-dsri-W@mr-node                                  ERROR     job_201405281644_0001  FAILED/KILLEDJA018     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000-140528164444736-oozie-dsri-W@fail                                     OK        -                      OK         E0729     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Check oozie logs to find why it was killed.